# Is __file and __dirname evaluated at compile or at runtime?

Tags: node.js

In node.js there are global variables `__filename` and `__dirname` - are they expanded by the compliler during the load time, similar to how it is done in c++ preprocessor to substitute `__FILE__` (and other magic constant) or are these evaluated at runtime?

I could not find this info anywhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Can someone edit this question so that the __ (2 underscores) are not removed by the markdown parser?

Comment: @Dmitri That's already been done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's declared as a variable before executing each file.

For entry-level files, this is done [deep in the source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js#L377-L380).

For normal modules, it's done [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/b55c9d68aa713e75ff5077cd425cbaafde010b92/src/node.js#L419-L422), as called [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L448-L449).

Comment: So it's only evaluated once during the loading of module and all instances of __file are then replaced with string representing file path? I just want to know if it's done only once during loading or each time the module is called.

Comment: @Dmitri: See my edit; the first piece of source I linked is only called in special cases.

Comment: For normal modules, the module source is wrapped in a function that takes these values as named parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now that __file is just a variable. It's not bad, but would be better if during load time it was physically replaces with a string - the path to the file. But not sure if it's even possible currently unless there is some sort of pre-processor involved during loading of modules.

Comment: @Dmitri: How would that be better? And what if you use it in a string literal or JSON property key, or declare your own variable?

Comment: if __file is replaced with string "/usr/local/lib/mymodule.js" then you can use it in logging. logger.info(__file + ": my message")
During loading of file all instances of __file are replaces. I understand this is how it's done in C++. But setting __file to variable is ok too.

Comment: @Dmitri: You can use it with logging as a variable too.  There is no reason to do substitution.

Comment: substituting with a string will avoid looking up variable at runtime. Tiny difference, but still alwasy looking for more efficient ways to do things in Node since it's all a single process.

Comment: I would imagine / hope that the JITter would do that automatically since it doesn't see any assignments.

Comment: V8 currently only does optimization with eye into one function at a time, it doesn't consider the full code-base at once. There is great benefit from inlining primitives instead of looking them up from globals or context objects, so if you are using a build step anyway you can use it to inline any such variable references. A grim example is a function that has switch case with labels that are not inlined, the entire function becomes unoptimizable.

Comment: @Esailija: These aren't globals; they're function parameters.

Comment: They are function parameters/locals to the top level scope in the module only, they are closure variables to any function defined in the module I.E. practically everywhere.